# \addcontentsline not writing files

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files

I try to make a custom list of answers as instructed by section 2.3 of *The LaTeX Companion, 2nd edition*.

I write this code to define my custom list:

```
\newcommand{\exerciseref}[1]{\hyperref[exercise#1]{Exercise #1}}
\newcommand{\declareexercise}[1]{\paragraph{Exercise #1} \label{exercise#1}}

\newcommand\l@answer[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{\exerciseref{#1}}{\pageref{#1}}}
\newcommand\addanswer[1]{\addcontentsline{ans}{answer}{#1}}
\newcommand\listofanswers{\section*{Answers}\@starttoc{ans}}
```

The command `\declareexercise` introduces a label referring to an answer of an exercise, and the command `\exerciseref` uses `\hyperref` to refer to a label created by '\declareexercise'.

According to the companion, I firstly define the command `\l@answer`, which uses `\@dottedtocline` to define the look of an answer appearing in the list. Then, I define the command `\addanswer`, which instructs LaTeX to write a contents line to the file `\jobname.ans`. Finally, I define the command `\listofanswers`, which starts the list by calling `\@starttoc`.

Then inside my file, I introduce the list somewhere at the beginning of the document, and I add the answers to the list at the end of the document, like this:

```
\listofanswers
some texts and some declaration of answers using \declareexercise...
\addanswer...
```

To my surprise, the result list only had a title introduced by the `\section*{Answers}`. And when I checked the .ans file, I found it empty. I am sure that I ran LaTeX more than twice, and the table of contents was correct.

What was wrong?

Comment: show a *complete* example that can be tested. Nobody can know from your snippets what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine.

Have you checked content of `.aux` file? It should contain line like

`\@writefile{ans}{\contentsline ...`

Have you checked that your `.ans` file is not locked for writing?

Also read log file, may be there some notes.

Comment: Thank you. I found that the file was not written for a mistake I made. See my answer.

Comment: I'v got no enough score to comment you amswer, so  I reply here. File .ans was epmty due to second problem.

Comment: Continue. "Level" is work because uoy have defined l@answer, other macros which uses snwer are set to \relax. That is why there is no errer message.

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems.

One problem:
The level used in the command `\addcontentsline` should not be "answer", since I do not define it. Otherwise, LaTeX would write section*2 to the command `\contentsline`. However, I don't quite understand why the undefined level "example" works fine in the companion's example:

```
\newcommand\ecaption[1]{\addcontentsline{xmp}{example}{#1}}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\listofexamples{\section*{Comments}\@starttoc{xmp}}
\newcommand\l@example[2]{\par\noindent#1,~\textit{#2}\par} 
\makeatother
```

The other problem was a mistake. I misspelled a letter in the name of the pagestyle I used to create the list. So somehow LaTeX ignored the whole page, and didn't write anything to the .ans file.